# IComparer not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, icomparable, icomparer

I have a problem where my custom IComparer is not being called. I am thinking that maybe it might have to do with me expecting for it to work with different objects? Why is it not being called?

The Icomparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<object>
{
    public string[] needles { get; set; }

    public MyComparer(string[] argument)
    {
        needles = argument;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int rankA = x.getRankedResults(needles);
        int rankB = y.getRankedResults(needles);

        if (rankA > rankB) { return 1; }
        else if (rankA < rankB) { return -1; }
        else { return 0; }
    }

}

public static class MyComparerExtensions
{
    public static int getRankedResults(this object o, string[] needle)
    {
        int result = 0;

        if (o.GetType() == typeof(StaticPage))
        {
            var orig = o as StaticPage;
            result = needle.countOccurences(orig.PageTitle.StripHTML(), orig.BodyCopy.StripHTML());
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(CustomerNewsArticle))
        {
            var orig = o as CustomerNewsArticle;
            result = needle.countOccurences(orig.Title.StripHTML(), orig.BodyCopy.StripHTML());

        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(Blog))
        {
            var orig = o as Blog;
            result = needle.countOccurences(orig.Title.StripHTML(), orig.Body.StripHTML());
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(PressRelease))
        {
            var orig = o as PressRelease;
            result = needle.countOccurences(orig.title.StripHTML(), orig.body.StripHTML());
        }

        return result;
    }

    //count the total occurences of the needles inside the haystack
    private static int countOccurences(this string[] needle, params string[] haystack)
    {
        int occurences = 0;

        foreach (var n in needle)
        {
            foreach (var h in haystack)
            {
                var nh = h;
                int lenghtDif = nh.Length - nh.Replace(n, "").Length;
                occurences = occurences + (lenghtDif / n.Length);
            }
        }

        return occurences;
    }

}
```

And how it is being called:

```
string[] needles = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
Haystacks.OrderBy(o=> o, new MyComparer(needles));
```

So "Haystacks" has 42 objects inside of different types (they are rows from different tables, and inside "getRankedResults" I detect the type of the object and choose the fields used to calculate the rank values). When i call the MyComparer on the sort, I can see the argument being set in the constructor, but then "Compare(object x, object y)" is never being called.

Comment: `OrderBy` looks like it might be a LINQ operator - in which case, it does nothing until you force evaluation to occur (which won't happen since you're not *assigning* the result of `OrderBy` to anything).

Comment: Assigning alone (`var foo = bar.OrderBy(x => x.Buzz);`) is not sufficient, the sequence must be iterated over, for example by creating a list from it (`var foo = bar.OrderBy(x => x.Buzz).ToList();`) or using it in a `foreach` loop (`foreach (var foo in bar.OrderBy(x => x.Buzz)) { [...] }`).

Comment: Thanks guys, all working good now! Can't mark any of your comments as an answer don't know why but i up voted them!